# Customize LookUp Field

Tags: lookup-column, custom-form, custom-field-types

Someone knows how to customize a LookUp field to make it look like it:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18929/An-OwnerDraw-ComboBox-with-CheckBoxes-in-the-Drop

(Dropdown + Checkbox).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I would suggest creating your own Field Type. That way you can customize it in which every way you want.

Link to a MSDN How-to for creating custom field types http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg132914.aspx